Does anyone know how to model this part?
How to model this part? Picture below


what have you tried?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Create a 6 vertex circle, subdivide twice, extrude up:

Move up these edges:

Extrude up the whole edge loop, right click > LoopTools > Circle:

Extrude up and scale, etc:

